# Temporarily disable scrolling when a location is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I’ve been having a look at this website - http://everylastdrop.co.uk/ and have been trying to work out how the page almost seems to stick for a while once reaching a certain position; for example at the very beginning as the sun comes up and as the shower curtain goes across in the bathroom. I am making a one page website and want to replicate this effect so that when the user reaches each page (div) the page sticks for a while allowing the parallax animations to still play through.
Many thanks, Jack

Comment: Seems fine in Firefox, awesome site btw

Comment: This is not my site by the way, I am using it as an example and want to know how to create a similar effect

Answer (score 0):

Try with jQuery:

```
$('body').on({'mousewheel': function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
       //then run smth you want to
   }
})
```